# How can I change a custom property name in Application Insights data

Tags: azure-application-insights

Is there a way to change the name of a custom property for existing page view data in Application Insights?

Answer (score 2):

You can change any properties on page view event before it left the browser with [telemetry initializer](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/master/API-reference.md#addtelemetryinitializer):

Add this code immediately after the initialization snippet that you get from the portal.

```
...
window.appInsights = appInsights;

// Add telemetry initializer
appInsights.queue.push(function () {
    appInsights.context.addTelemetryInitializer(function (envelope) {
        var telemetryItem = envelope.data.baseData;

        // To check the telemetry item’s type:
        if (envelope.name === Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Telemetry.PageView.envelopeType) {
            // this statement removes url from all page view documents
            telemetryItem.url = "URL CENSORED";
        }

        // To set custom properties:
        telemetryItem.properties = telemetryItem.properties || {};
        telemetryItem.properties["globalProperty"] = "boo";

        // To set custom metrics:
        telemetryItem.measurements = telemetryItem.measurements || {};
        telemetryItem.measurements["globalMetric"] = 100;
    });
});
// end of insertion

appInsights.trackPageView();
```

Also, you can rename columns at the query time in the Analytics query by aliasing them or copying them:

```
pageViews | summarize sum(itemCount) by NameB=tostring(customDimensions.NameA) | ...

pageViews | extend NameB = customDimensions.NameA | ...
```

Comment: I have a typo in the original custom property name that has been in use for quite some time.  It would be great if there was a way to fix it, so that queries against the data don't have to continue using the misspelled property name.

Comment: @Tyler, I think the only way is using extend to add a new column with correct name during query, as Dmitry mentioned in the end of his answer.